# how to compare last element of a list with last element of another list in prolog?

Tags: list, prolog

I want to find rhyming couplets of a poem so I need to compare last syllables of two verses of the poem.

```
cmp([A|As], [B|Bs]) :- cmp(As, A, Bs, B).

cmp(A, [B], B, [A]).
cmp([_, A|As], X, [_, B|Bs], Y) :- cmp([A|As], X, [B|Bs], Y).
```

I need, for example, to check if "[They, put, me, in, the, oven, to, bake]" and "[Me, a, deprived, and, miserable, cake]" rhymes, so I suppose I should check if last elements of these two lists are the same.

With this code i tried to compare first and last elements of my lists but it doesn't work neither.

Answer (score 1):

Some Prolog systems provide a lists library with a `last/2` predicate that you can call. The usual definition is:

```
last([Head| Tail], Last) :-
    last(Tail, Head, Last).

last([], Last, Last).
last([Head| Tail], _, Last) :-
    last(Tail, Head, Last).
```

Note that this definition avoid a spurious choice-point, thanks to first-argument indexing, when calling the predicate with a bound list.

Using the `last/2` predicate you can write:

```
compare_verses(Versus1, Versus2) :-
    last(Versus1, Word1),
    last(Versus2, Word2),
    same_last_syllable(Word1, Word2).
```

You will now need to define the `same_last_syllable /2` predicate. That will require breaking a word into a list of syllables. That doesn't seem to be trivial (see e.g. https://www.logicofenglish.com/blog/65-syllables/285-how-to-divide-a-word-into-syllables) and I'm not aware of a open source Prolog library performing it.

Comment: Maybe OP can use soundex or [double metaphone](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=double-metaphone)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need, at least in part, a way to identify the last element of a list:

```
last_of( [X], X ).
last_of( [_|X], Y ) :- last_of(X, Y).
```